# Remove extra horizontal width from overflow wrapping with flex

Tags: css, flexbox, overflow, width

Essentially, I am trying to remove/prevent the extra horizontal width created when a horizontal row of block elements has any of the block elements wrapped. That is, I want the width of the `div` containing the overflow elements to be just the size of the nonwrapped elements.

The following code can be used to see the issue in question:

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="example.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-content">
      <div>
        <div class="row">
          <p class="note-title">This is a relatively lengthy example title for example purposes.</p>
          <div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="note-tags-list">
                <p id="blank-tag">.</p>
                <p class="tag note-tag">crunchy</p>
                <p class="tag note-tag">recipe</p>
                <p class="tag note-tag">carrot</p>
              </div>
              <p id="text-that-should-stay">I stay</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

```css
/* example.css */
@import "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.3/css/bulma.min.css";

#text-that-should-stay {
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: white;
}

#blank-tag {
  width: 30px;
  min-width: 30px;
}

.note-title {
    white-space: nowrap;
    color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.card {
    background-color: black;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.note-tag {
  width: 175px;
  min-width: 0px;
}

.note-tags-list {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 24px;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

For ease, the code above can be seen in the following JSFiddle, though running the above code locally will produce the same result: https://jsfiddle.net/5L7u2gkp/1/.

Here is a gif that shows the issue and then what would be ideal visually:

[image: Issue gif]

Comment: why use `.blank-tag` ? that is important?

Comment: @AhmadMRF I use `.blank-tag` so that all non-blank tags can overflow. Try removing `.blank-tag` and rerunning the JSFiddle.

Answer (score 4):

##### SECOND EDIT

I might not get you right, but there is no extra width when you remove the blank tag.

[image: no extra width]

If you are talking about the *gap* between `node-title` and `note-tags-list`, it derives from `flex-grow: 0;`, which is the default for flex items. You can add to `.tag` the [`flex-grow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow) property as `flex-grow: 1;` and it will make your tags grow to the maximum space they can get.

```css
@import "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.3/css/bulma.min.css";

#text-that-should-stay {
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: white;
}

.note-title {
    white-space: nowrap;
    color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.card {
    background-color: black;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.note-tag {
  width: 175px;
  min-width: 0px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.note-tags-list {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 24px;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-content">
    <div>
      <div class="row">
        <p class="note-title">This is a relatively lengthy example title for example purposes.</p>
        <div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="note-tags-list">
              <p class="tag note-tag">crunchy</p>
              <p class="tag note-tag">recipe</p>
              <p class="tag note-tag">carrot</p>
            </div>
            <p id="text-that-should-stay">I stay</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

##### EDIT - based on your comments

so actually, the excess width is coming from the `#blank-tag`. You set its width to `30px`. If you remove it / change its width to 0, it will solve your problem. Otherwise, there will always be a 30px gap.

---

the

> "pink" width

It is not related to the width of your elements; it's how chrome devtools represent the position of your elements when you use `flexbox`. You can (and should!) read more [here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/css/flexbox/).
You can check it yourself by changing the width of the `div` in the devtools to 202px (as seen in the picture you added), and you'll see there will be no change in the display.

Comment: Oh, I got that. However, the width is what it is because of the presence of the overflow elements.

My goal is to always have the width set to the width of the elements that have not overflowed. That is, I wish for the elements that have overflowed to act like they are nonexistent (have no effect on the width of their container) similar to how `display: none` works in the CSS.

Comment: so just to clarify: you want the width to always be set to 3X (if x is the width of the element) but for the overflow to always be the same?

Comment: Not quite. Let us say that the container X has children Y1, Y2, and Y3. If Y3 is the only overflow element, then container X is the width of Y1 and Y2 (excluding overflow element Y3). If Y2 and Y3 are the only overflow elements, then container X is the width of Y1 (excluding overflow elements Y2 and Y3). I hope that clarifies it!

Comment: Yeah it does, but it works that way now. ..

Comment: I tried to clarify the issue a bit more. Please see the slightly revised code and gif.

Comment: There is still extra width even if the blank tag is deleted that is caused explicitly by the overflow elements.

Comment: Regarding edit 2, the issue still exists without the blank tag as can be seen here: https://i.imgur.com/UWE8L5l.mp4 (First, I delete the blank tag, which does remove a bit of space, but there is still extra space. Then, I delete the overflow element, which removes the extra width.) As far as the `flex-grow` solution goes, [see my responses to Ahmad MRF's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72158410)

Comment: Oh, I see your comment there. though I can't understand what is the expected outcome? do you want the tags to have space between them while taking into account the full row width? or anything else

Comment: I just don't want the text to wrap early due to the space between the text and tag container div. I want it to wrap at the first tag.

Comment: OK. that's solvable! it was really unclear

Comment: Sounds good. I'll look forward to your edit then.

Answer (score 1):

Its because of `flex-flow: row wrap;`

To clarify, The *flex-flow* wrap's the content inside `.note-tags-list`,When the space is not enough to display items inside it(crunchy|recipe|carrot),Vertically,The items that are placed vertically are not visible,as there is fixed height to one of its parent.

[image]

***The answer is to remove `flex-flow: row wrap;`***
See [This fiddle-fork](https://jsfiddle.net/ze01s86t/)

Comment: Hi, Neptotech. This does prevent the wrapping, which does in turn prevent the extra space mentioned in the question. However, I was looking for a solution in which the wrapping (or an equivalent effect) can occur without the width of the container being affected by the wrapped/overflow items (only the elements that are showing/not overflowed) as if the overflow items had `display: none`.

Answer (score 1):

what do you think about this answer? i only slightly changed the HTML codes.
i change the `min-width` of `.note-tag` and set a `flex-grow` for it.
and now ...

> I want the width of the `div` containing the overflow elements to be just the     size of the nonwrapped elements.

is working

```css
@import "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.3/css/bulma.min.css";

#text-that-should-stay {
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: white;
}

.note-title {
    white-space: nowrap;
    color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    border: 1px dashed blue;
}

.card {
    background-color: black;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.tags-list{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  border: 2px dashed green;
}
.note-tag {
  min-width: 175px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.note-tags-list {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    gap: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 24px;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    border: 1px dashed red;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-content">
    <div>
      <div class="row">
        <p class="note-title">This is a relatively lengthy example title for example purposes.</p>
          <div class="tags-list">
            <div class="note-tags-list">
              <p class="tag note-tag">crunchy</p>
              <p class="tag note-tag">recipe</p>
              <p class="tag note-tag">carrot</p>
            </div>
            <p id="text-that-should-stay">I stay</p>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is much closer to what I was looking for in that the excess width is no longer there. However, I was looking for the widths of the tags to solely depend on the text that each tag contains instead of having each tag try to fill up the tag container.

Comment: If there is no way to have the tag container's width be equal to that of the non-overflow elements, then I would also be open to an option where the title overflow ignores the aforementioned excess width and nothing is pushed off the screen.